# Does AChartEengine support oscilloscope-like bar charts to display digital input/output?

Tags: android, achartengine, oscilloscope

To display digital input or output signal chart. It should look like steps without gaps

```
  ___      ______
_|   |____|
```

The problem is that y-value should be the same until next y-value is received and now
it just draws line between two values and it looks like:

```
 /\/\/\/\/\/\
```

Comment: In the title, you mention bar charts. Why are you drawing line charts then?

Comment: because neither bar nor line charts does not look as i expect in order to dispay digital input/output signal

Comment: Please hold constructive way of talking, Dan. I've found public void drawSeries(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, List<Float> points, SimpleSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer, float yAxisValue, int seriesIndex, int startIndex) {} method and found float halfDiffX = getHalfDiffX(points, length, seriesNr);  It's BarChart class. It's non-configurable behaviour. May be, one should introduce new chart type, but BarChart seems to be the closest.

Comment: Don't look at the ACE source code. It's not that what you need to modify. You probably want to use its APIs and build an application against it. What else have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the 1.1.0 nightly build of AChartEngine [here](https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.1.0/) and try again. If it still doesn't work then please post some code.

In the title, you mention bar charts. Why are you drawing line charts then?

Comment: i've extracted the code from http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/ and it does not support it. BarChart looks like that (blue) http://www.achartengine.org/dimages/combined_chart.png

Comment: What means "does not support it"?

Comment: Bar charts can look in an infinity of ways. It depends how you need it to look like.

Comment: Exactly. "Does not support it" i mean that i can't just configure existing classes using setters for example. I have to create separate chart inheritor with specific behaviour (bar width calculation)

Comment: Exactly: "It DOES support it". You just need to figure out the APIs.